# Is it possible to change the face that represents each person on Photos.app on OS X 10.10?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I'd like to change the thumbnail selected by Photo.app for some of the people on the `Faces` album, but I can't seem to find that option. Also, consolidating some of the suggested names –which I suppose are contacts in some of the cases– would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right-click on the `Faces` album you'd like modify, and click `Get Info`.
2. Double click the small round photo that appears on the fifth row of the info pop-up. All photos in that album will now appear behind this pop-up.
3. Right-click the photo you that you want to use as that Faces album thumbnail, and click `Make Key Photo`.

Answer (score 1):

Also works:

1. Double click on the face album you'd like to change
2. Select `Faces` on the second row from the top of the app (`Caras` in Spanish)
   [image: ("Caras" is Faces in Spanish)]
3. Right click on the face you'd like to select for the thumbnail and select `Make key photo` from the pop-up menu.